# Using AJAX to send form information to another page using a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello I have two files that are supposed to be connected to one another. I want to send an AJAX request to another page that uses a sql query to send form information.

The application that I'm trying to create is a questionnaire with eight questions, each questions has four answers paired together with the same id (qid) and each answer has a value from the database. After you answer eight questions you will see a button that sends an AJAX request to the page test.php, (named submitAJAX).

The problem is that although my connection with AJAX is working, the values from the form are not being sent to my database. Previously I thought that the problem may lie with the form page, but now I I think the problem lies in this file:

**test.php (file with json)**

```
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password) or die ("Kunde inte koppla");
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');
if(count($_GET) > 0){
   $answerPoint = intval($_GET['radiobtn']);
   $qid = intval($_GET['qid']);
$tid = intval($_GET['tid']);
   $sql2 = "INSERT INTO result (qid, points, tid) VALUES ($qid, $answerPoint, $tid)";
   $connect->query($sql2); 
   $lastid = $connect->insert_id;
   if($lastid>0) {
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>1));
}
   else{
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>0));
} 
}
?>
```

I think that the problem may lie in the row where:  `if($lastid>0) {`
$lastid should always be more than 0, but whenever I check test.php I get this message: `{"status":0}` What's intended is that I get this message: `{"status":1}`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password) or die ("Kunde inte koppla");
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');

$qid = 1;
if(count($_POST) > 0){
    $qid = intval($_POST['qid'])+1;

}


?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="qid" id="qid" value="<?=$qid?>">
<?php
$sql1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where answer != '' && qid =".intval($qid));
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1)){
?>
<input type='radio' name='answer1' class="radiobtn" value="<?php echo $row1['Point'];?>">
<input type='hidden' name='tid' class="tid" value="<?php echo $row1['tid'];?>">
<?php echo $row1['answer'];?><br>
<?php
}
?>
<?php if ($qid <= 8) {  ?>
<button type="button" onclick="history.back();">Tillbaka</button>
<button type="submit">Nästa</button>
<?php } else { ?>
<button id="submitAjax" type="submit">Avsluta provet</button>
     <?php } ?>  
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#submitAjax").click(function(){
        if($('.radiobtn').is(':checked')) { 
            var radiobtn = $('.radiobtn:checked').val();
            var qid = $('#qid').val();            
             var answer = $('input[name=answer1]:radio').val();
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET",
                url: 'test.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: "radiobtn="+radiobtn+"&qid="+qid,
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response.status == true){
                        alert('points added');
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('points not added');   
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
});
  </script>

    </body>
```

The values that I want to send to my database from test.php are:

qid(int), tid(int), Point(int)

There is a database connection, and my test.php file's sql query should work, but its not sending form information. Is there something that I need to rewrite or fix to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**, your data parameter in the AJAX call is not using the correct syntax.  You're missing brackets.  It should look like:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ radiobtn: radiobtn, qid: qid }),
```

**Second**, I'd suggest using POST instead of GET:

```
type: "POST",
```

which means that you need to look for your data in $_POST['radiobtn'] and $_POST['qid'] on test.php.  NOTE:  you should check for the key you expect using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) before assigning the value to a variable, like so:

```
$myBtn = isset($_POST['radiobtn']) ? $_POST['radiobtn'] : null;
```

**Third**, for testing, use a console.log() inside your condition that checks for the checkbox being checked in order to verify that condition is working as expected.

```
if($('.radiobtn').is(':checked')) {
    console.log('here');
```

### **UPDATE:**

**Fourth:**  You should specify the content type in your AJAX call, like so:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: Shouldnt it be datatype: JSON.stringify on the first one?

Comment: No.  datatype should be json, not json.stringify.  json.stringify is not a datatype, it's a function.

Comment: Hello, I tried to use POST instead of GET but nothing appears when I check test.php file when I do so.

Comment: use your browser dev tool (F12) to verify the POST payload is being sent as expected when the AJAX call is triggered.  if that looks correct, then please show how you are attempting to access the $_POST variables in test.php

Comment: I've tested it, and I get no errors and POST is being sent. I'm unsure if this is how I'm supposed to make this work: TEST.PHP http://codepaste.net/77ds2h

Comment: if POST looks ok, then I'd recommend you hard code the POST values in test.php for testing purposes and enable php error reporting.  Then bring test.php up in a browser to run the code.  Add echo or var_dump statements after each variable assignment and verify you're getting the results you expect line by line.

Comment: Also, I've added another change to my answer.  You should specify the content type in your AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks @devlincarnate The problem that I'm having right now whenever I use POST instead of GET is that the array message {"status":0} doesnt show, I can also insert values into my table doing it this way, but only once. I really feel like the problem may lie here: "if(count($_GET) > 0){" since the conditions are not met on test.php status message 0 shows up instead of 1...

Answer (score 1):

> [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) *returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute.*

In your SQL, you are providing the ID yourself, there is no auto-increment. So you should get **0** from `$connect->insert_id`, because *the function returns zero if there was no previous query on the connection or if the query did not update an `AUTO_INCREMENT` value*.

For your purpose, you can use the `return` value of [mysqli_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) instead, which returns `TRUE` on success and `FALSE` on failure.

```
if($connect->query($sql2)) {
   echo json_encode(array('status'=>1));
}
else{
   echo json_encode(array('status'=>0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you execute your query that inserts the result you can use a sql statement to select the last insert id. Try something like

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO result (qid, points, tid) VALUES ($qid, $answerPoint,         $tid)";
$connect->query($sql2); 
$result = $connect->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$lastid = $row[0];
```

That should return the correct last insert id, if that was where your error was occurring.